# Autorotate Portrait mode documents if it is showing as landscape

Tags: ios

In my app user scans(captures photos of) documents. For uploading to the server.

I want to programmatically detect the document's orientation. 
It looks like this.

[image]

And then user tap that circular arrow button and make it portrait.
Then it looks like this

[image]

I want to do this rotation task automatically.
Please let me know how we can do this, I never came across this kind of requirement.

Comment: Are you able to access the document's size dimensions?

Comment: @Dare It is coming via camera